# view with nested relationships

Tags: entities, views

I have 3 node types. A, B and C.

A has an entity reference to B. B has an entity reference to C.

A has a list field. One of the values is "4". I need to display all node of type C where the top parent of type A has the value 4 in this list field.

I created a 'relationship referencing entity:field_in_type_a_reference_to_type_b'. And I created a context filter 'provide default value:4' with the relationship.

This part works. Only nodes of type B with parent nodes with list value '4' are displayed.

But I need the filter for one reference level deeper, for nodes of type C. I created one more relationship referencing entity:field_in_type_b_reference_to_type_c with the relationship. I tried this relationship with and without the other relationship.

But with no success. Nodes of type C aren't displayed.

How can I get the relationship from C to A?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're starting with node type B, whereas you should be starting with node type C.

- Create your view with appropriate filters so that you only see nodes of type C
- Add a "Entity Reference: Referenc*ing* entity" (not "Referenc*ed* entity) relationship for the B->C entity reference field, give it an identifier of something like "Entity B", tick "Require this relationship
- Add another "Entity Reference: Referenc*ing* entity" relationship for the A->B entity reference field, use relationship "Entity B", give it an identifier of "Entity A", tick "Require this relationship
- Add a filter (a regular filter, not a contextual one) requiring that your field has a value of "4", use relationship "Entity A"

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps in view.

1. First add Entity Relationship "A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via field_a_refer" i.e content type A which is referred in content type B.
2. Then add Entity Relationship "A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via field_b_refer".In relationship dropdown of this select "Content referencing Content from field_a_refer".
3. For each fields that you want to display, select from Relationship "Content referencing Content from field_b_refer".
4. In Filter add filter for value 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a good explanation with structured pictures, related to your problem. http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/making-sense-drupal-views-relationships-and-entity-references

By reason below i will add this.
On this site you get a good lead on the difference between REFERENCING and REFERENCED when adding an Entity Reference as as a Relationsship in VIEWS. 
The example adding relations and walking up-streams and down-streams in three related Nodes-content-types crelation, to get the right Node related to the Views relation. The trick is to understand the Entity relations "two way relations" and use it in Views.

Comment: Hi Göran, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand - copyright's on pages ie from this site who has picture and text. If the page not say "free to copy" it's a bad idea to copy picture and text (against the law). But in the Principe I agree with your technical argument, and when possible i will do it your way. ;)